# como guardar una tabla html en mysql y después mostrarla

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta tabla la guardo en mysql pero al pedirla de la base datos no aparece la tabla solo una linea, ya intente diferentes formas pero no me sale

Comment: Bienvenido @DieterLahnstein te invitamos a visitar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga una mejor comprensión por toda la comunidad.

Comment: en html tienes que iterar forzosamente si lo quieres hacer con js y ajax, necesitarias un each $(.tabla).each(function(a){ iteras los rows y los insertas }), de igual manera cuando regresas los dato de mysql por lo regural se regresa en json, te llega el objeto de json y lo iteras formando la tabla, se me olvida la parte mas importante, necesitas un servicio jejejeje, bueno si lo haces con php, lo puedes pasar directo!

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría asi:
Haria una tabla en MySQL como si fuera tu tabla html solo que vacía
Haría que cada elemnto de mi tabla (la que quiero guardar) sea una variable, y la guardaría en SQL con el INSERT y al pedirlos solo los llamo con un SELECT, y ya ordenaría los datos que salen en el html.

Answer (score 1):

Si literalmente quieres almacenar la tabla html, en tu atributo de la DB que tu tipo de dato sea un varchar de mas de 1000 ccaracteres, y cuando devuelvas los datos a traves de tu petición, muestralos utilizando jquery,

ejemplo

```
puede ser mediante post o get 
$.get("rutaArchivoPHP",{parametro: valor}).done(function(data){
                const htmlAjax = data;
                $("#idInfoAjax2").html(htmlAjax);
            })
```